# Зависает страница от большого количества <video>

Tags: html, jquery

Ребят, добрый день! Нужна идея. Есть страница в которой находится такой список:

```
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item">Заголовок</li>
  <video src="videos/v1.mp4" controls></video>
  <li class="list-item">Заголовок</li>
  <video src="videos/v1.mp4" controls></video>
  <li class="list-item">Заголовок</li>
  <video src="videos/v1.mp4" controls></video>
  <li class="list-item">Заголовок</li>
  <video src="videos/v1.mp4" controls></video>
  <li class="list-item">Заголовок</li>
  <video src="videos/v1.mp4" controls></video>
  <li class="list-item">Заголовок</li>
  <video src="videos/v1.mp4" controls></video>
  <li class="list-item">Заголовок</li>
  <video src="videos/v1.mp4" controls></video>
  <li class="list-item">Заголовок</li>
  <video src="videos/v1.mp4" controls></video>
  <li class="list-item">Заголовок</li>
  <video src="videos/v1.mp4" controls></video>
  <li class="list-item">Заголовок</li>
  <video src="videos/v1.mp4" controls></video>
  <li class="list-item">Заголовок</li>
  <video src="videos/v1.mp4" controls></video>
</ul>
```

Ещё есть кусочек Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('video').hide();
  });
$(".list-item").click(function() {
    $(this).next("video").slideToggle(1000);
  }
);
```

Который позволяет кликнув по заголовку(элементу списка) развернуть находящееся под ним видео, и свернуть его, если оно уже развернуто.

Этот список будет выводиться посредством php. Но проблема в том, что когда страница открывается, то браузер очень сильно виснет. Можно ли как-то оптимизировать все это? Я думал присваивать тегу video значение атрибута src, только после клика по заголовку, но не знаю как это сделать, ведь пути к файлам будут доставаться из Бд средствами php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надо изначально в php выводить видео с атрибутом `display: none;`

Comment: сейчас попробую, спасибо)

Comment: Все отлично) спасибо ещё раз, иногда очевидные вещи под носом, а я уже начал думать как бы массив с адресами из php передать в jquery и присваивать их по клику нужному элементу)

Comment: Бывает, такое, да )